# Problem in installing ROS in Ubuntu 18.04 (Bionic)

Tags: apt, gnupg, ping, ros, keyserver

I set the proxies that is needed to connect to internet unable to PING to google , I used the command "ping google.com" but it did not show up anything and I am facing difficulty when trying to get the key from keyserver to install ROS in Ubuntu 18.04, I have used the command " sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-key 421C365BD9FF1F717815A3895523BAEEB01FA116", it showed the error - "gpg: keyserver receive failed: Connection timed out", please tell me about the error and how to solve it.

Comment: Your problem is not related to ROS, seems you got your proxies set wrong... you have to crate a new question and explain who did you set the proxies to make us able help you... your connection to internet has some problem which we have no Idea what it is until you explain what you have done.

Comment: Thanks for the answer problem solved, yes there was some error with the internet proxy which i set to correct ones and connected.